# Cannot use fortran code from f2py compile function

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

I have the following Fortran code:

```
    !routines.f90
    module mymodule
       contains

         function add(a, b)
             real(8), intent(in):: a
             real(8), intent(in):: b
             real(8) :: add
             add = a + b
         end function
    end module
```

Instead of using the command: `python -m numpy.f2py -m routines -c routines.f90`, I want to compile from within a python script, as follows:

```
#main.py
import numpy as np
import numpy.f2py as f2py

with open(r'routines.f90', 'r') as f:
     source = f.read()

 f2py.compile(source, modulename='routines')

 print('OK')
```

But when I try to execute this script: `python main.py` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    f2py.compile(source, modulename='routines')
  File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/f2py/__init__.py", line 59, in compile
    f.write(source)
  File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 485, in func_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Could you please tell me what is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`open(r'routines.f90', 'r')` opens your file for reading *text* (a.k.a. `str`), but, apparently, `f2py.compile` requires that its first argument be of type `bytes`. To satisfy that, open your file in binary mode:

```
open(r'routines.f90', 'rb')
```

(Also, there's no need for the first `r` in `r'routines...'`, you can just do `'routines.f90'`, although it doesn't change much).

Comment: Now I have another compilation issue with f2py which expect a fixed form fortran file, so I have start all my fortran code at 7'th column to solve that. Could you please tell me how to tell f2py use free form fortran source file? thank you

Comment: Add the argument `extension='.f90'` to the `compile` function call.